# How can I fill empty raster cells with values from another raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic

I have 2 rasters:

1 that has many gaps in between pixels:
[image]

And one that is more filled:
[image]

I want to fill the empty cells from raster 1 with the cells from raster 2.  Cells that are filled in raster 1 should be kept.

How can I do this using QGIS?

Comment: I think that answer will depend on what you mean by"empty": NoData?  Zero? -999999?

Comment: what is the value of empty cells?